# How to bind through collection?

Tags: collections, clojure

How do I match values through a list? In my case I have a list of colors -

```
["Black", "Lavender", "Brazen", "Army", "Birch"]
```

I have this function that creates a collection of the color name and a related URL:

```
    (combine-color-imgurl get-product-images)
=>
[("Black"
  "example.com/WWbNhro1n3YfmQTx1q5Piv1j8lZzse6M-25_2a353315-9965-457f-83f8-32af89f3b067.jpeg")
 ("Lavender"
  "example.com/trWCTNYNOfiA8EBX9HZcxVB1Hg8pVtr9-25_403cbe3e-9894-4ad6-9f69-dedcfd7ef77b.jpeg")
 ("Brazen"
  "example.com/COYrBHEsiOgdeOfxsQGcw8XXynsVdpxy-25_af0a9ff9-b988-467e-9b39-c4ae572420e8.jpeg")
 ("Army"
  "example.com/YWKhJXFM0dKhJuRXphCXD4TWstnZRRJm-25_b3a2e43c-3c8c-4abc-83d2-d00d9b3ed594.jpeg")
 ("Birch"
  "example.com/IRsHVjavdFsybvmpT6xjnpKqMtjyjeoZ-25_6321e4ef-5bed-463f-990a-1857151b8a11.jpeg")]
```

I'm not exactly sure how to get only the URL related to the color.

So the function would be something like

```
(defn get-url [color]
  (some-operation (combine-color-imgurl get-product-images)))

=> URL
```

Comment: If your `combine-color-imgurl` function returned a map instead of a vector of lists, it would be trivial to get the `url` once you have `color` (i.e. `(colors-urls color)` where `colors-urls` is the map returned by `combine-color-imgurl`).

Comment: Got a friend to help me out - he did exactly this!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Juan, the solution was to have `combine-color-imgurl` return a map then use

```
(get (into {} (combine-color-imgurl get-product-images)) color)
```

to get the URL.